Working out an average based on text in Excel
Hoping someone can help me, as I cant get my head around how to work out what the average rating of a team score would be, based on a formula!
I have four teams, with scores rated from Excellent to Poor.  How would I create a formula to show what the average score is?  I have attached a screenshot below for clarity. So for eg, if a team has 50% in Excellent, and 50% in poor, it would return 'Good' as the average. Whereas if another team could have 25% in Good, and 75% in poor, so it would return Poor as the average team rating.
Thank you in advance for your help!


Excel doesn't have a built-in function to calculate an average based on text ratings like Excellent, Good, Poor.
You can assign a numerical value to each text rating (e.g., Excellent = 3, Good = 2, Poor = 1) and then use the AVERAGE function to calculate the average of those values. You can then use a separate table to convert the numerical average back to a text rating.

Edited to rewrite
Rethinking this, I think the difficulty here is working backwards from a derived value (the percentage of excellent, good, and poor from a sample of employees each with their own rating for the entire team) to be able to get the average of the entire team.
Imagine a team of 6 people with the following ratings (1=poor, 2=good, 3=excellent):

We can quickly get the average as 2.16666 using =AVERAGE(B3:B8). The trouble is that you don't have this individual rating information available. You only have the percentage of the team that is rated at each level.

I believe you can derive that average once again using the following formula:
=(E23)+(F22)+(G2*1)
Which you can use a vlookup like so:

This Vlookup doesn't look up against a range. Instead it looks up against a two-dim array. You could just as easily store those values in a range and do the look up traditionally too if you like.
This will output "poor" for a team average between 1 and 1.66, "good for a team average between 1.66 and 2.33, and "Excellent" for a team average above 2.33. Feel free to tweak.

Hi there, thank you very much for your reply!  In the last example, what is the vlookup looking for? There doesnt appear to be a reference cell in the formula?

Im not sure the above works - so if I have a team of 2, and they both score 'poor', there would be 100% in the poor column. But as its returning 50% according to the formula, the outcome comes out as 'good', even though it is poor?

I've completely rewritten the question to show how to back into the team's average score and then attach that poor, good, excellent value to the average. Hoping that this is more in line with what you were thinking.

I think you mean =XLOOKUP(1/3,C2:E2,$C$1:$E$1,,1)
As you work with the average of 100% (equals 1) divided by 3 buckets, the average would always be 1/3 if you lookup the value greater than 1/3 and return it's header, you get your average bucket.
